No results when using BigQuery to search GDELT
I want BigQuery to report the number of articles and the average tone for certain institutions, going back to 2011 if possible.
My code is
SELECT   
  AvgTone,
  NumArticles
FROM `gdelt-bq.full.events`
WHERE Year = 2013
AND (Actor1Name= 'European Banking Authority')


This indicates that 25gb of data will be used, but the query returns no results

BigQuery is a SQL database optimized for analytics.  You have shown a SQL query that returns a couple of columns from a table with a filter.  I am assuming that the table is a data table that you have access to.  You shouldn't assume that the readers of this thread know anything about.  If there are no results, then that implies that no rows matched your filter.

Hi Kolban - thanks. I was hoping my title would refine suggestions from users familiar with the GDELT database. The search result implies that a large European institution was not mentioned by global media at all for an entire year. I don't think this is likely, so I'm hoping for help improving my code

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
